# js - var defined twice

Tags: javascript, var

I am trying to figure out why this code gives 21 and not 26? My idea was that when `add_t()` is being called, the value of sum changes to 25. At the same time, I'm not sure if the fact that it's a `var` affects the answer

```
var sum = 20;
function add_t() {
  var sum = 25;
}
add_t();
console.log(sum+1);
```

Comment: Inside `add_t`, you're defining a new separate *local* variable which happens to have the same name as the outer one. (Don't shadow variables like this, it's confusing)

Comment: it's a midterm question, that's the point! thank you tho

Comment: This is abc type question for JS programming. So make some study then ask question in community like stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The second declaration declares `sum` in the scope of `add_t`, and only exists inside those brackets (it gets declared there as a totally different variable and then is never used). If you had something like this (without declaring a new variable of the same name inside the function)

```
var sum = 20;
function add_t() {
  sum = 25;
}
add_t();
console.log(sum+1);
```

Then you would get 26 in the console because it would reference the `sum` in the outer scope.